# orthogonal group and spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology

In [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#Homotopy_groups) it says theres a fibre bundle $O(n)\to O(n+1) \to S^n$, and for each point $x$ on $S^n$, $O(n)$ acts on the hyperplane perpendicular to the vector $x$. Can someone give me an explicit formula, given $x \in S^n$ and matrix $A$ inside $O(n)$, the corresponding matrix in $O(n+1)$?

I only can do this if $x$ is of the form $(0,...0,1,0,...0)$. In other words I'm asking for an explicit bijection identifying $U \times  O(n)$ with $p^{-1}(U)$, where $U$ is a neighbourhood of $x\in S^n$ that makes this a fibre bundle. Thanks

Comment: Why not take a an orthogonal change of basis so that $x$ is of the desired form?

Comment: yes base change thanks for reminding me

Comment: yes base change thanks for reminding me